# Xamarin iOS: Edit cells of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**I have set of images and want to have the functionality of 'Drag to reorder' I am using UICollectionView for that.**

If the view inherits from `UICollectionViewController` then I can do this directly
i.e.,

```
 public class SimpleCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
    {}
```

by overriding `CanMove` and `CanMoveItem` delegates.

```
   public override bool CanMoveItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Checking if it can move the item");
                return true;
            }


public override void MoveItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath)
    {
        //base.MoveItem(collectionView, sourceIndexPath, destinationIndexPath);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Started moving item");
        var item = animals[(int)sourceIndexPath.Item];
        animals.RemoveAt((int)sourceIndexPath.Item);
        animals.Insert((int)destinationIndexPath.Item, item);
    }
```

**But my current view is not inheriting from UICollectionViewController so how can I use 'UICollectionViewController' delegates to reorder the items inside the UICollectionView**

I added Objective-c and swift tag as this question is not related to Xamarin but iOS architecture in general.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign an object that inherits from `UICollectionViewSource` [1] (or object that implements `IUICollectionViewSource` interface [2]) to the `UICollectionView.Source` property, e.g.:

```
collectionView.Source = new MyUICollectionViewSource();
```

`UICollectionViewSource`/`IUICollectionViewSource` basically combine a `UICollectionViewDelegate`/`IUICollectionViewDelegate` and a `UICollectionViewDataSource`/`IUICollectionViewDataSource` into one class/interface. You will note that a `UICollectionView` [3] has properties to assign Delegate, DataSource, and Source objects. If you only need the DataSource methods, which both CanMoveItem and MoveItem are DataSource methods, then just use an object that inherits from `UICollectionViewDataSource`/`IUICollectionViewDataSource` and assign that object to the DataSource property of the collection view.

**UPDATE:** Some clarification about the difference between `UICollectionViewSource` and `IUICollectionViewSource` (or Delegate or DataSource). Delegates and DataSources in iOS are Obj-C protocols (not sure what they are called in swift). Obj-C protocols are kind of like C# Interfaces, but Obj-C Protocols can have required and optional methods while all of the methods in an Interface must be implemented by the inheriting class. So when Xamarin binds protocols, they make a class from the protocol that has all required and optional methods in it, so you can just override the ones you need, but we also make an Interface which only has the required methods of the protocol because we do not want to force you to implement the optional methods of the protocol. However when a class inherits from the Interface version, `IUICollectionViewSource` for example, you will only be able to override the required methods but you can still add the optional methods to the same class that is implementing the interface. And you can inspect the class version of the protocol, `UICollectionViewSource` for example, to see the signature of the optional methods and then just implement them in the class that is implementing the Interface version of the protocol. For more info see [4].

To implement the optional methods for a protocol when implementing the related C# Interface, you will have to use the `[Export()]` attribute to register the method with the iOS runtime. E.G., to implement the CanMoveItem and MoveItem optional methods of the DataSource:

```
[Export ("collectionView:canMoveItemAtIndexPath:")]
public bool CanMoveItem (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // Do stuff
}

[Export ("collectionView:moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:")]
public void MoveItem (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

The easiest way to find the Obj-C selector to use with the `[Export()]`attribute, right click on the `IUICollectionViewDataSource` in your source code and select "Go to Declaration(XS)/Definition(VS)" and the Assembly browser will open. Look for the Protocol Member that has a Name that matches the method you want to implement. The Selector property is the Obj-C selector that you want to use in your `[Export()]` attribute.

[1] https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionViewSource/

[2] https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.IUICollectionViewSource/

[3] https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionView/

[4] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/#Protocols

Comment: Hi @jgoldberger
The IUICollectionViewDataSource only has `GetItemCount` and `GetCell` functions. It does not have `CanMoveItem` and `MoveItem`.

Comment: ~jgoldBerger, Thank you for your answer. Its working now. But I am stuck on another issue. When the cellzise is small, the MoveItem and canMove are not being called. Only when the cell size is large, MoveItem and CanMove are called. I posted the new question on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248063/xamarin-uicollection-image-reorder-issue) Can you please help me out with that?
Thanks.